# "New File" feature for OS X?

Tags: applications, file

back in the day (2006-07), before the Intel Mac days, I used an application called NuFile which let me create a "new file" like Windows on the fly. Ever since i've been searching for alternative but have been unsuccessful.

Do you guys know of any new apps that will allow this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to point you to the following [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/41311/14832). Open up Automater and select "Service" in the "Choose your type for your document" Dialog. Afterwards use the apple-script in the linked answer and you can now run the service via: Finder --> Services --> Create new File

Setup in Automator:
[image: Automater]
Create new file in service menu of finder:
[image: CreateNewFile]

Answer (score 1):

[Neu](http://www.elegantchaos.com/neu) allows you to do this. It's shareware and is currently priced at $10. There is also a fully functional free demo you can use. You can purchase it from MAS or from within the demo version.

[About Neu](http://www.elegantchaos.com/neu):

> Neu is a simple application that makes it easier to create new documents in the Finder, without you having to open an application first.
>
> It does this by adding **"Create Document..."** and **"Create And Open Document..."** menus to various places, including the main menubar, the Dock, and the Services menu that the Finder shows when you right-click on something. You can also trigger Neu from any application using a special key combination.
>
> Neu lets you choose what to make from a list of templates, which are simply existing files. Once you've chosen a template, Neu creates a copy of it, brings the Finder to the front, and selects the new file.
>
> Neu comes with some pre-defined templates, but you can add your own, so you can customise the types of new file available to suit your needs. It can make a blank text file, an empty letter, a shopping list, or anything else that you want. You can have one template, or a hundred - it's up to you.