# How to assign a keyboard shortcut to create an empty text file in Finder?

Tags: macos, keyboard, finder

I like that `Cmd+Shift+N` creates a new folder in the current directory in Finder.
I would like to have a similar command like `Cmd+Control+N` or `Cmd+Control+Shift+N` that creates an empty text file in the current directory.

There's quite a bit of discussion on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/14118/easiest-way-to-create-a-new-text-file-in-a-finder-window-on-osx) and on this site, [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/104820/new-file-feature-for-os-x/104834) and [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41250/what-is-an-quick-way-to-create-a-new-blank-file-in-lion?lq=1).

However, some of the solutions seem out of date, others are mouse driven, or involve somewhat elaborate multi-click processes.

**How can I assign a shortcut key like `Cmd+Control+N` to create a new empty text file in Finder on OSX?**

Comment: Was there a solution you figured out(that could possibly help others)?